# PostgreSQL: plv8.start_proc

Tags: postgresql, plv8

Set up startup procedure in config

```
plv8.start_proc = 'plv8_startup'
```

Created function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION plv8_startup ()
RETURNS void AS
$body$

  this.hello = function(name){
     return name + ', hello!';
  };

$body$
LANGUAGE 'plv8'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY DEFINER
COST 100;
```

Under postgres user everything works well:

```
DO $$ 
  plv8.elog(NOTICE, hello('John'));
$$ LANGUAGE plv8;
```

the result - John, hello!
Then created user test and tryed to run the function:

```
ERROR: ReferenceError: hello is not defined
SQL-state: XX000
```

tryied to grant user test on execute plv8_startup - the result is the same.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It was my bug - function was created not in public schema, so system could not start it under the test user rights/